# Memory leak in C# timers

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, timer

at first i have to say that the problem only occurs on Windows Server 2008R2 and Windows Server SBS 2011.

I'm programming a program which automatically searches for updates and write the into a database and I have some problems with memory leaks. Every time the timer calls a function the memory usage increases. But the GC should work properly because on my Win10 Pro client the memory usage didn´t increases. The servers and my machine are running the same programversion and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

The memory usage increses every minute by around 10Mb.

To measure the memory leaks i´m using dotMemory.
dotMemory shows that the var updateString remains in the memory after executing the uptime function.

I´m creating 5 Timers but only one of them are runing every minute.

This is how the timer looks and starts:

```
Timer t1 = new Timer(zeit); // Timer anlegen
t1.AutoReset = true;
t1.Elapsed += uptime;
t1.Start();
```

And the function the timer calls looks like this:

```
        public void uptime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string value = getUptime.Days.ToString() + "|" + getUptime.Hours.ToString() + "|" + getUptime.Minutes.ToString();
                string updateString = "UPDATE server SET Uptime = \"" + value + "\" WHERE ID = " + ServerID;
                db("update", updateString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMsg("Fehler beim aktualisieren der Uptime@@@" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

db() contains folowing code:

```
        public string db(string art, string statement, string param = "")
        {
            try
            {
                using (var wb = new WebClient())
                {
                    var data = new NameValueCollection();
                    data["passwd"] = "supersecurepasswd";
                    data["art"] = art.ToLower();
                    data["statement"] = statement;
                    data["params"] = param;

                    var response = wb.UploadValues("supersecurelink", "POST", data);
                    string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                    return responseInString;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                UpdaterServiceLog.WriteEntry(
                    "Verbindung mit dem Websocket kann nicht hergestellt werden\n" + ex.Message,
                    EventLogEntryType.Error);
                return "ERROR";
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
        }
```

errorMsg() contains following code:

```
        public void errorMsg(string message, int art=0)
        {
            try
            {
                message = message.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
                message = message.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
                message = message.Replace("\'", "\\\'");
                message = message.Replace("\t", "t");
                message = message.Replace("\r", "r");
                message = message.Replace("\n", "n");
                message = message.Replace("\b", "b");
                message = message.Replace("@@@", "\n");

                string statement = "INSERT INTO error (ServerID, Text, Art) VALUES (" + ServerID + ",\"" + message +
                                   "\", " + art + ")";

                db("insert", statement);
            }
            catch
            {
                string statementFail = "INSERT INTO error (ServerID, Text, Art) VALUES (" + ServerID +
                                       ", \"Fehler beim Eintrgen eines Fehlers!\", " + art + ")";
                db("insert", statementFail);
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
        }
```

After calling the function db() and errorMsg() I call the GarbageCollector and on my machine the memory consumption decreases but not on the servers.

I'm really sure that this isn't the right way to start a timer but I don´t know how to do it properly.

I know that the GC can´t collect all the data from the called function while the subscriber is still alive, but the timer needs to run every x minutes and can´t be disposed.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: What does `db()` do?  I suspect your memory leak might be in there, if it's real at all.  This needs a [mcve].  How many timers are being created?

Comment: Show us the code of db

Comment: You should figure out what part is increasing memory exactly, you might be able to cache or dispose it. Also just some advice from another non-native English speaker, don't program in your own language, the programming language is structured so it looks like English sentences, this way its a mix of 2 languages.

Comment: How have you measured this memory leak?  What tool did you use?

Comment: As others have said, I strongly suspect the issue is not with your timers, but with the database connectivity. Leaving database connections open is the most common cause of memory leaks I run into.

Comment: Also, how do you know it's a memory leak?  Did you use a profiler?  What evidence do you have that you have a memory leak?  What tool did you use to gather that evidence?

Comment: @J... I´m calling four more timers but this is the only one which is called every minute. The db function calls a websocket

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I´ve used dotMemory